# StringFormat percentage

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms app, I want to show a percentage in my `Label` with 2 decimal places, something like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Percent, StringFormat='%{0:C2}'}" FontSize="24"/>
```

Is there a way to do this in XAML, or do I need to make a converter for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work just fine without any converters, however `{0:C2}` will also return a currency sign.

More information about formatting can be found in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).